# What is the difference between the chattr and setfattr command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfs, xattr

At the Veeam Documentation, I read that the chattr and setfattr commands need to be supported:

- https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/hardened_repository_limitations.html?ver=110

I have read the following man pages:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfattr.1.html

I figured out that chattr is used to set attributes, e.g. `cattr +i <filename>` makes a file immutable.

But for what is the setfattr comand in context with Veeam used for? I searched for hours but did not figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Veeam is backup software, so its goal is to be able to restore any file to *exactly* as it was, all file attributes included. Apparently it uses `setfattr` on restore to set extended attributes, if a backed-up file originally had them.

Extended attributes could be anything: SELinux security tags are handled by some filesystems as a specific form of extended attributes, for example. Veeam uses `setfattr` since it can handle *all* extended attributes, not just SELinux-specific ones.